# Specman Parametrized Unit

Tags: unit-testing, parameterized, specman

I Need to verify a paramterized module in verilog, for example:

```
module A #(PAR1, PAR2, PAR3) (/*input, outputs*/);
```

This module is instantiated several times with different values of parameters.

I need to generate a SPECMAN Unit which can get PARAMETERs as constant for variable/port declaration.
Those parameters are also used for logic calculation.

I could not find a way to pass PARAMETERs to a specman unit as it can be done in verilog.

Is it possible?

If not - are there alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to pass parameters to units in *e*. What you can do in your case, however, is used a template:

```
template unit some_unit of (<len'type>) {
  some_sig : in simple_port of <len'type> is instance;
    keep soft some_sig.hdl_path() == "some_sig";
};
```

The code above will define a template for a unit that contains a port, whose length is specified when declaring the unit instance. Here's how you can instantiate two units with different lengths:

```
extend sys {
  unit1 : some_unit of (uint(bits : 2)) is instance;
  unit2 : some_unit of (uint(bits : 4)) is instance;
};
```

You can find a working example on [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/MFx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in *e* you can define **template** struct or units. However, note that the parameters would be types rather than values.
For example, you can have a declaration like this:

```
template unit my_unit of (<first'type>, <second'type>) like base_unit {
    ......
};
```

and then you can instantiate it like this:

```
extend sys {
    foo: my_unit of (int(bits: 16), uint) is instance;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access Verilog parameters via simple_ports from e-code, just bind them like normal signals. 
But it wouldn't help in this case because the values can't be used in other port declarations. I suggest to use the solutions offered here or make the ports wide enough to capture all requirements (MSBs would be filled with 1'b0 by Specman per default).

Comment: Making the ports wide enough is not a stable solution. Was tried but it makes problems when comparing random values.
The solution of parametric type in template unit was precise.